# Symfony authentication token getCredentials returning null

Tags: php, symfony, authentication, single-sign-on, token

I have a `TokenAuthenticator` which implements `SimplePreAuthenticatorInterface`, `AuthenticationSuccessHandlerInterface` and `AuthenticationFailureHandlerInterface`. It creates a `PreAuthenticatedToken` token.

Within that class I have a method called `authenticateToken` which looks like this.

```
/**
 * @param TokenInterface        $token
 * @param UserProviderInterface $userProvider
 * @param $providerKey
 *
 * @return PreAuthenticatedToken
 */
public function authenticateToken(TokenInterface $token, UserProviderInterface $userProvider, $providerKey)
{
    $token = $token->getCredentials();
```

The code works, however there have been a couple of occasions recently where `getCredentials` has returned `null` causing the code to fall over.

I am trying to ascertain why this is and have considered users using private browser sessions and/or clearing their session cookies/cache etc, but I cannot seem to replicate this.

Considering the `authenticateToken` method type-hints the `$token` variable to a `TokenInterface` - what would cause a call to `getCredentials` to then return `null`?

Answer (score -1):

Are you requiring all authentication for all routes?

If you allow anonymous users `getCredentials` will return `''`, as you can see in this snippet from the class

```
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function getCredentials()
{
    return '';
}
```

The other default token class that returns this is the `RememberMeToken`.

Comment: Thanks, but i'm not sure this helps. Not all of my routes require authentication, but this one particular one does.

Comment: what do you get when you dump `get_class($token)`?