# Symfony token getCredentials returns null

Tags: php, symfony, authentication, single-sign-on, token

I created a way to authenticate a user with API keys, thanks to a class `A` implementing the `SimplePreAuthenticatorInterface` interface. Everything works well (the user is successfully authenticated).

I'm trying to store the API keys, for a later use during the user's journey. To do so, inside the authenticate method of my class `A`, I return a `PreAuthenticatedToken` in which the credentials are my API keys.

The problem is : Inside a custom service, when I try to get the token credentials, I get `null`... I successfully get the API keys when I comment the line 76 of the `PreAuthenticatedToken` Symfony core class :

```
public function eraseCredentials()
{
    parent::eraseCredentials();
    //$this->credentials = null;
}
```

My questions are:
1) Why is the method `eraseCredentials` called whereas the user is authenticated? I thought this method was called during user's logging out...
2) What am I doing wrong? Is the `PreAuthenticatedToken` token the right place to store my API keys? How can I get them back from a custom service ?

Thanks for helping me. :)

PS : I'm a newbee on posting in Stackoverflow (and in English ^^). Sorry in advance for any mistakes.

I found [another similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42337634/symfony-authentication-token-getcredentials-returning-null) but it has no helping response and I added some more precisions.

**EDIT**: The code of my custom service where I try to get the credentials is:

```
$token = $this->container->get("security.token_storage")->getToken();
if ($token !== null) {
  $credentials = $token->getCredentials();
  // $credentials is null here
}
```

**EDIT 2**: The return part in my code of my `SimplePreAuthenticatorInterface::authenticateToken` method :

```
return new PreAuthenticatedToken(
    $user,
    $apiKeys,
    $providerKey,
    $user->getRoles()
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ad 1. It depends on your `AuthenticationProviderManager`: this class accepts `$eraseCredentials` as second parameter - by default set to `true` ([here](https://github.com/symfony/security/blob/master/Core/Authentication/AuthenticationProviderManager.php#L43)).

That's why `eraseCredentials` method is being called on `PreAuthenticatedToken` `$token` during authenication ([here](https://github.com/symfony/security/blob/master/Core/Authentication/AuthenticationProviderManager.php#L91)).

Ad 2. Please check [How to Authenticate Users with API Keys](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/api_key_authentication.html) tutorial. You should create your custom `ApiKeyAuthenticator` class and add logic there.

According to your comment:

Note that `authenticateMethod` from tutorial is being called inside `authenticate` method ([here](https://github.com/symfony/security/blob/master/Core/Authentication/AuthenticationProviderManager.php#L76)). At that time token credentials are not erased yet and you can access them. For security reason they are erased after authentication (but this can also be changed / configured via [security.yml](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/security.html) file). If you need them later you can introduce custom token class and store API key there.

Comment: For 1) : I didn't know about `AuthenticationProviderManager`. But I read that it's for security reason that `eraseCredentials` is called even if the user is authenticated.  
  
For 2) : I just edited (EDIT2) my question for your answer. My api keys are stored in the credentials of the token according to the tutorial. That's why I don't understand how the tutorial allows me to get back my api keys when actually `eraseCredentials` is called...

Comment: I know the question is pretty old, but I would really like to know what settings should be used in security.yml in order to prevent the suppression of credentials after authentication. Can this be done without the need for a custom AuthenticationProviderManager?

Comment: Well, in case anyone else is looking for the answer, the value of erase_credential for AuthenticationProviderManager can be set in security.yaml. Under security:, just add erase_credentials: false